# Cannot Find relation in AWS Lambda calling redshift

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3

Hi Have a database that's structured like this on redshift:

[image]

Then I am trying to call vault control which has a column name solution_name like this:

```
select distinct(solution_name) from vault_control;
```

The query works on an IDE:

[image]

but I'm getting relation vault_control doesn't exist. I tried to chain it via cloudbi but it didn't work either.

Here's the error message:

```
Execution f11d86c5-28fd-45d3-a1bf-7b1bf6dfb finished with status FAILED
Failed with Error: ERROR: relation "vault_control" does not exist
```

Here's the code:

```
import json
import boto3
import time


query_string = "select distinct(solution_name) from vault_control";

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('redshift-data')
    execution_id = client.execute_statement(
    ClusterIdentifier='id',
    Database='cloudbi',
    DbUser='user',
    Sql=query_string,
    )['Id']
    print(f'Execution started with ID {execution_id}')




    status = client.describe_statement(Id=execution_id)['Status']
    while status not in ['FINISHED','ABORTED','FAILED']:
        time.sleep(10)
        status = client.describe_statement(Id=execution_id)['Status']
    print(f'Execution {execution_id} finished with status {status}')


if status == 'FINISHED':
    columns = [c['label'] for c in client.get_statement_result(Id=execution_id)['ColumnMetadata']]
    records = client.get_statement_result(Id=execution_id)['Records']
    print(f'SUCCESS. Found {len(records)} records')

else:
    print(f'Failed with Error: {client.describe_statement(Id=execution_id)["Error"]}')
    


return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

I am able to get the execution id, but the status goes to failed.

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be testing your query in an IDE or in the Management Console v2 query editor to make sure your query is working before moving it into Lambda.

In Redshift the default search_path for the schema is "public" so if you don't designate a schema it will look in public.  You can fix this in two ways:

1. [Set the search_path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html) with a query like `"set search_path to vault_control;"`
2. Or better is to just designate the schema in the query like:

`"select distinct(solution_name) from vault_control.aws_billing_config;"`

More generically, `"select * from schema.table"`

Comment: I tested it, it works. In lambda it doesn’t work, it says cannot find relation. I tested it on an editor and it worked but doesn’t work on lambda.

Comment: I've edited the query to show that the query works on an DBeaver.

Comment: What is the name of the actual table you're querying?